# How I finish this question about system of congruence $X \equiv a \pmod n, X \equiv b \pmod m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> My question: For a,b,n,m $\in N$, with n, m $>1$. Show that:
>   \begin{align}
> X \equiv a \pmod n\\
> X \equiv b \pmod m
> \end{align}
>   if and only if, $a \equiv b \mod (n,m)$ and if $(m,n) = 1$, then is only solution modulo $mn$.

My solution:

\begin{align}
x = nk + a\\
x= mk_1+b\\
0 = nk + a - mk_1 - b\\
b-a = nk - mk_1
\end{align}

for diophantine equation exist solution if $(n,m)| b-a \to b\equiv a \mod (n,m)$.

My problem is how I can prove the back, I wrote only this:

\begin{align}
a\equiv b \mod (m,n)\\
\to (m,n) | a -b \\
\to a -b = (m,n)k 
\end{align}

Comment: Have you considered looking at proofs of the Chinese Remainder Theorem for inspiration? This is basically the wording for the Chinese Remainder Theorem, IIRC.

Comment: What do you mean by $a \equiv b \pmod(n,m)$ ?

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA I fixed.